# MySQL how do I save a count into a variable to update another column?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with columns:

```
IdNum, NameEmployee, IdInsurance, NameInsurance, num_employees_not_insured
```

Some employees don't have insurance so `IdInsurance` and `NameInsurance` are null.

I want to count how many employees don't have insurance and put that in the last column.

I tried:

```
UPDATE MajorTable2
SET num_employees_not_insured =
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MajorTable2)
    WHERE 'IdInsurance' IS NULL);
```

and next I tried "saving the result of counting null rows to a variable" like (but I'm guessing what's in single quotes does not count as a variable):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'NULL_values_in_IdInsurance'
FROM `MajorTable2`
WHERE `IdInsurance` IS NULL;

UPDATE MajorTable2
SET num_employees_not_insured = 'NULL_values_in_IdInsurance';
```

How can I fix my logic and syntax?  I know some Python but my SQL is super rusty.

Comment: Why do you want to update every row with the number of people not ensured? From a design point of view this seems very wrong. Either calculate it on the fly, or place this attribute in a another table with aggregated data is my suggestion

Comment: @Lennart it's a HW problem so just testing to see if I can do this

Comment: `UPDATE MajorTable2 AS m CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM MajorTable2) WHERE IdInsurance IS NULL) AS g SET m.num_employees_not_insured = g.cnt;`

Comment: Your last attempt (saving into a variable) is correct as well but you need to check how to use variables. Single quoted strings is not the correct way.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @cnt
FROM MajorTable2
WHERE IdInsurance IS NULL;  UPDATE MajorTable2
SET num_employees_not_insured = @cnt ;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to overcome the limitations in MySQL regarding updates:

```
WITH T (n) as (
    SELECT count(*) - count(IdInsurance) from MajorTable2
)
update MajorTable2 set num_employees_not_insured = (
    SELECT n from T
);
```

A slight modification of ybercubes comment is:

```
UPDATE MajorTable2 AS m 
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(*) - COUNT(IdInsurance) AS cnt 
    FROM MajorTable2
) AS g 
    SET m.num_employees_not_insured = g.cnt;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0c72cf64e1981f230e21fda4bf97ed74)